# composition of power relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

maybe easy answer but i have to be sure.. I used search and did not find this. So Lets say i have set R:{(1,2)(2,3)(3,1)(3,4)}. And i want to make a composite relation of it. So R²(R◦R) is {(1,3)(2,1)(2,4)(1,2). But now the question, how i count R³ and so on? That composition between two sets is easy. I just look (1,2) -> (2,3) so 2 relates these two so it makes (1,3) etc..

But what if we have R³(R◦R◦R)? Is it R²◦R?

Comment: [Composition of relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) is associative.